# Yii2: how to modify data column of a GridView without using a model

Tags: gridview, model, yii2, dataprovider

I made a SqlDataProvider with `product` and `price` columns in my controller.

Then I used a GridView in my view to show both columns but I need to concatenate **$** with the **price** so I can show, for example, **$ 75**.

I know how to do it with a model but in this case I don't have a model.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'product',
        [
            'attribute'  => 'price',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return '$ ' . $model->price; // I don't have a model so it doesn't work here.
            }
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: If it isn't a mdel, maybe it is an array (i don't know your code) so $model['price'].

Comment: You are right @Sfili_81.

Comment: I hope it was useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'product',
        [
            'attribute' => 'price',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return '$ ' . $model['price'];
            }
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```